# Is it possible to setup live typescript type checking in Vscode virtual workspaces

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, virtual

I am using Vscode to edit my typescript projects in virtual workspaces which I am connecting to through SSH FS extension.

Whilst benefitting from the convenience of remote access I have had to forego all of the benefits of live typescript checking that Vscode automatically provides for projects in local storage.

Is there a way to combine the best of both worlds and have live typescript checking in virtual projects? I realise this is out of scope of vscode usage and that documentation suggests its not possible (at least not by design), but vscode seems super flexible so I am wondering if anyone has been able to achieve this?

Comment: I am trying to achieve exactly that, no luck so far...

Comment: also posted to github repo https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147874please feel free to add comment, follow and support.